# Easy way to fix global variables in PHP 5.4?

Tags: php

I have a project with lots global variables.

Examples used in functions

```
function ChangePassForm( $VARS ) {
    global $tpl, $iBtns, $db;
...
    $db->query("....");
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I can pretty easy guess what the question is:

**"Why is it not working"?**

**ANSWER from [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php):**
[image]

Anyway I voted to close the question.
@Piotr please refine the question or it will be closed.